# Change color Office UI Fabric toggle

Tags: css, reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I am trying to use Office UI Fabric components in my application. I would like to change the color of the toggle component, it's default color is blue. How can I do it?

Comment: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-ui-fabric-react/wiki/Component-Styling

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to create and use a new theme. If your app is red instead of blue, you can create a red theme and all of the blues will now be red.

https://aka.ms/themedesigner